# Custom thankyou redirection if there is no products from specific category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, orders, taxonomy-terms

I have a function, that redirects WooCommerce checkout page to a custom site.

This code is working well, but I would like to enable that code only, if the product category is not "egyeb".

This is what I tried, but need some code for my condition:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'jupiterx_redirect_woocommerce_thankyou_page' );

function jupiterx_redirect_woocommerce_thankyou_page() {
    // Make sure we are on the thank you page.
    
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) || empty( $_GET[ 'key' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Our custom URL address.
    $custom_url = site_url( '/idopont-regisztracio' );
 
    // Redirect client.
    wp_safe_redirect( $custom_url );
 
    // Exit to prevent an infinite loop.
    exit;
}
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

The following will allow you to check that there is no order items from "egyeb" category, enabling a redirection from order received endpoint to a custom page:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'jupiterx_thankyou_custom_redirect' );
function jupiterx_thankyou_custom_redirect() {
    global $wp;

    // Only for thankyou page
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && ! empty($_GET['key']) && isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ) {
        $order_id    = absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']); // The order ID
        $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object
        $egyeb_found = false; // Initializing

        // loop through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item  ) {
            // Check for "egyeb" category
            if ( has_term( 'egyeb', 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                $egyeb_found = true;
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
        }

        if ( ! $egyeb_found ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/idopont-regisztracio' )); // Redirect customer
            exit(); // Exit to prevent an infinite loop.
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.